# Changing font color in listing numbers

Tags: color, listings, code, lstlisting

- I want to **change the font color in a listing**.
- I want only several lines in the listing to change its color (e.g. 1, 2, 9, 10, 12, 13). That is, I want to apply the color to **individual lines** of the listing.
- I want the **line number** that match the colored lines to be colored as well (e.g. 1, 2, 9, 10, 12, 13).
- I want the color to be expressed in **HTML (hexadecimal)** format.
- I am including the listing's content from a **separate file**.

How can I accomplish this?

This is my snippet (the included listing is now local for demonstration purposes):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{custom_grey}{HTML}{818181}

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  moredelim=**[is][\color{custom_grey}]{@}{@},
}

\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=10
  \else
    \ifnum\value{lstnumber}>10
      \the\numexpr\value{lstnumber} + 5\relax%
    \else
      \arabic{lstnumber}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers = left, style=base]
@#First comment@
@...@
'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss'
|Code line|
--------------------------------------------------------
========================================================
|Code :: line|
========================================================
@#Additional comment@
@...@
'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss'
@#End comment@
@...@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When changing the `lstlisting` environment into a `\lstinputlisting` call, the code is formatted correctly for me (also with the red highlight). Could you be more clear about what exactly fails for you? Also, the syntax for RGB and HTML color schemes is defined in the [`xcolor` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf).

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below may help you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{custom_grey}{HTML}{818181}

\lstdefinestyle{base}{
  moredelim=**[is][\color{custom_grey}]{@}{@},
}

\renewcommand\thelstnumber{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=1
{     \color{custom_grey}\arabic{lstnumber}}%
\else
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=9
{     \color{custom_grey}\arabic{lstnumber}}%
\else
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}=12
{     \color{custom_grey}\arabic{lstnumber}}%
\else
\arabic{lstnumber}%
  \fi\fi\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[numbers = left,
style=base]
@#First comment@
@...@
'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss'
|Code line|
--------------------------------------------------------
========================================================
|Code :: line|
========================================================
@#Additional comment@
@...@
'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss'
@#End comment@
@...@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Glad to know that my suggestion helps you...